# XMLHttpRequest onloadend Event not Running on Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Is there an event that'll run whether on success or error with Node.js's XMLHttpRequest module? According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/loadend_event), the onloadend event should trigger both on error and success, but it only runs on success. For example:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require( 'xmlhttprequest' ).XMLHttpRequest;

var url = 'https://www.example-bad-url.com/json.php';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open( 'GET', url );
xhr.send();

xhr.onloadend = function() {
    // This should get logged, but it doesn't.
    console.log( 'The request has completed, whether successfully or unsuccessfully.' );
}
```

In the above script, onloadend doesn't run, why? The URL doesn't exist, so it should trigger onloadend as an error and log "The request has completed..." but the callback function never runs, why?

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem with the native browser version of `XMLHttpRequest`. Your code runs as expected and I see the console.log() after the requests throws the error. But since you're running node, why are you using xmlhttp? You can use `http.get()` from the http module. Or `new Request()` from the rquest module. Or even node-fetch from the library. So importing xmlhttprequest would be my last choice when working with node.

Comment: It works in browser, this problem is Node.js-specific. The reason I'm using XMLHttpRequest is to have cross-platform code. I'm also trying to understand why it works in browser but not with Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xmlhttprequest` library for node.js does not fully implement the spec correctly.

If we dig into the code on github, we see the following line of code:

```
  if (self.readyState === self.DONE && !errorFlag) {
    self.dispatchEvent("load");
    // @TODO figure out InspectorInstrumentation::didLoadXHR(cookie)
    self.dispatchEvent("loadend");
  }
```

So the `load` and the `loadend` event handlers are only triggered when there is NOT an error, consistent with our observations where

```
xhr.onloadend = function() {
    // This should get logged, but it doesn't.
    console.log( 'The request has completed.' );
};
```

will only log when the event succeeded.

My advice would be to trigger the event manually in the `.onerror()` handler, which does work. Keep in mind that this is a 3rd party node.js module, not a native one.

Personally I just wrote a small wrapper around xmlhttprequest that mimics the `.fetch()` interface. The node.js version uses the native node.js `http` library and the client side version uses xmlhttprequest.

That way I can use the same `.fetch()` API for both front end and back end code, and just let the system decide if it'll use native fetch, xmlhttp powered fetch, or http powered fetch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As a developer, I get really disappointed when objects that are supposed to work the same cross-platform, don't. I really feel that specs should be followed so that we, as developers, know what to expect no matter what platform we develop in.